# is there a way to access the datatypes of each column from str() function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, internals

when calling str() on a df, it lists out all the datatypes: int, num, factor etc. Is there a way to access these datatype part of the str to find out how many factor columns and numerical columns are there?

Comment: Alternatively you could use an `apply` with class to do the same thing: `table(sapply(iris,class))`